# MPMediaPickerController closes after startup (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, alarm, mpmediapickercontroller

When I click on the cell to open the MPMediaPickerController it opens when it starts up.

[image: gif]

```
class MediaViewController: UITableViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
           let mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: MPMediaType.anyAudio)
           mediaPicker.delegate = self
           mediaPicker.prompt = "Select song"
           mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
           self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems  mediaItemCollection:MPMediaItemCollection) -> Void {
}

func mediaPickerDidCancel(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("MPMediaPickerController - Cancel")
}
```

Comment: try self.navigationController?.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @PPL Put it in didSelectRowAt?

Comment: yes, try and see

Comment: @PPL Its not work

Comment: @PPL Im see this 2018-03-20 17:57:46.435913+0500 Alarm[6928:2790899] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Alarm.MediaViewController: 0x10521bae0>.

Comment: this occurs when you try and display a new viewcontroller before the current view controller is finished displaying

Comment: @PPL Im tested this code in my another project and he is work perfectly

Comment: is it working for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please add this in your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(app Name) uses music</string>
```

It works for me.

Comment: Im have this <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$Alarm uses music</string>

Comment: there should be some other issue with this, as your code looks well

Comment: & don't know why it dismisses to root screen? share your first navigation code please

Comment: The first is where is the cell with the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167182/discussion-between-ppl-and-b2fq).

Comment: ok I changed the code a bit now everything works fine))) Thanks